# How to get start date assign to end date

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a ADF application which required to select (Drop down calendar) "Start Date" and "End Date". Currently when select Start Date, End date not automatically adjust to Start Date. It shows current date. Is there a way I can archive this without using Java bean?

I tried to add "pageFlowScope" to action and call the value to end date through minimum Value. This doesn't give result.

```
<af:inputDate id="id3" autoSubmit="true" autoComplete="on"
      converter="javax.faces.DateTime" immediate="true"
      action="#{pageFlowScope.dateOne}">
</af:inputDate>

<af:inputDate id="id4" autoSubmit="true" autoComplete="on"
       converter="javax.faces.DateTime" immediate="true"
       value='#{pageFlowScope.dateOne}"'>
</af:inputDate>
```

If Start Date Selected : "2019/05/05"
   End Date Selection start with  : "2019/05/05"

Jdeveloper : 11g
Deployed on Glassfish : 3.1

Comment: Suggest checking the docs to see if this is the expected behaviour: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/developer-tools/adf/12.2.1.4/develop-faces/using-input-components-and-defining-forms.html#GUID-E660F766-49CE-4066-BC28-52FBB47F3458

Comment: Our project done on Jdeveloper 11g version and deployed in Oracle Glassfish 3.1 version. Will give it a try with this docs.

Comment: ALWAYS include product version when posting questions!

Comment: Sorry my bad. I go through the document but cannot find the solution. I saw af:chooseDate and chooseId can be used. But I cannot make drop down calendar with chooseDate.

Comment: I suggest you post on the JDeveloper ADF community forum, Have you tried that? That is usually the best choice to look at first. https://community.oracle.com/community/groundbreakers/java/java_development_tools/application_development_in_java/jdeveloper_and_adf/

Comment: Here's the docs for the component. minValue and maxValue may help - or it may not do what you want. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/apirefs.1112/e17491/tagdoc/af_chooseDate.html

Comment: I found a this [link](https://vtkrishn.com/tag/afinputdate/)

It use bean for assign data to end date. For now this is the best I can find.